# Simple MySQL query seems really slow

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a table with about `26` million records. There is a `isProcessed` flag and a `timestamp` column and I want to select the earliest not processed record. Currently there are about `5` million records with `isProcessed == 0`.

I execute the following query, which finishes in about `40` seconds.

`select * from EventData where isProcessed=0 order by timestamp ASC limit 1;`

I have ascending index on `isProcessed` column and also ascending index on `timestamp` column. Do I need a compound index on both columns?

What am I doing wrong? The query seems really simple.

Comment: Try selecting only one column and run it again to see if it's the "*".

Comment: Have you tried `EXPLAIN SELECT ... etc` ?

Comment: Take a look at "EXPLAIN": https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html

Comment: @Tony Stark - Unfortunately selecting only one column doesn't increase the performance.

Comment: 26 million records is a lot and your doing a comparison on an element in each of the 26 million records as well as you are doing comparisons on the timestamps with the order by. Although the code is small and simple, it is actually doing a lot of stuff. 
Try doing the search without the order by, and then try without the comparison and see if that drastically changes the time required.

Comment: Actually the query finishes in about 40 seconds, which is really slow, but it is not minutes.

Comment: Explain gives me -  `id = 1, select_type = SIMPLE, table = EventData, type = index, possible_keys = processed, key = timestamp, key_len = 4, rows =   2, filtered = 470396416.00, Extra = Using where`

Comment: The fact that `timestamp` is a reserved word might mean that your query is ordering by timestamp rather than the timestamp field: try `SELECT * FROM EventData WHERE EventData.isProcessed = 0 ORDER BY EventData.timestamp ASC LIMIT 0, 1;`

Comment: @CD001 - `select * from EventData where EventData.isProcessed=0 order by EventData.timestamp ASC limit 1;` still takes about `40` seconds.

Comment: @Nickknack - Without `order by` it works under a second, and without the comparison also under a second. But when both are there - it takes about 40 seconds. Will it help if I create a compound index on both columns?

Comment: According to the MySQL docs there are certain circumstances where an index on `ORDER BY` won't be used, including : *The key used to fetch the rows is not the same as the one used in the ORDER BY* (e.g. your `WHERE` column is different to the `ORDER BY` column). So, just for the sake of an experiment, could you try `SELECT * FROM EventData WHERE EventData.timestamp < NOW() ORDER BY EventData.timestamp ASC LIMIT 0, 1;` see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: Your query executes immediately.

Comment: Hmmm ... now try adding the `isProcessed` clause back into that `SELECT * FROM EventData WHERE EventData.timestamp < NOW() AND EventData.isProcessed = 0 ORDER BY EventData.timestamp ASC LIMIT 0, 1;` *fingers crossed*

Comment: It took again 40 seconds :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two separate indexes is *not* the same as a composite index.  You need, in this order,

```
INDEX(isProcessed, timestamp)
```

With that, it can find the one row in the index that is desired, then promptly reach into the data.

"finishes in about 40 seconds" -- since `INDEX(isProcessed)` was essentially useless, it did a table scan of 25M rows.

Comment: And `DROP` your `INDEX(isProcessed)`.

Comment: A compound index made the query under a second :)

Answer (score 0):

If isProcessed can have only two possible values 0 or 1; it's better to not have it indexed. full table scan is faster in such cases; Try this query and see if it helps. `mysql> SELECT * FROM EventData FORCE INDEX (timestamp) WHERE EventData.isProcessed = 0 ORDER BY EventData.timestamp ASC LIMIT 0, 1;` Also it is a better practice to not use reserved words like timestamp as a column name.

Comment: I executed your query but again about 40 seconds :(

Comment: Based on the processing hinted at, I will guess that all the _old_ timestamps have isProcessed=1.  Hence `FORCE INDEX(timestamp)` will have to wade through all of them before finding the first one with =0.